# Prove difference of infinite series of decreasing function and its integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, solution-verification

$f(x)$ is continuous and decreasing on $[0, \infty]$, and $f(n) \to 0$.  Let ${a_n} = f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(n-1) - \int^{n}_{0}f(x)dx$.  Show $a_n$ converges (from *Mattuck Analysis*).

**Edit:** My solution is below.  Can you please:

1. Verify the proof
2. Is it well written? How would you improve the writing?
3. Is it a good approach? Would you take an alternate approach?

**Solution:**

For any continuous function $f$ and integers $a, b$, with $b > a$, let $L(f, a, b)$ be the Riemann sum of the lower bound of each unit subinterval $[a, a+1], [a+1, a+2]...[b-2, b-1], [b-1, b]$, and $U(f, a, b)$ be the Riemann sum of the upper bound of each such unit subinterval.  Then, by definition of integral, $L(f, a, b) \leq \int_a^b f(x)dx \leq U(f,a,b)$.  Since $f(x)$ is decreasing, for any unit subinterval $[m, m+1]$, $f$'s upper bound is $f(m)$ and its lower bound is $f(m+1)$.  Therefore, $a_n = U(f,0,n) - \int^n_0f(x)dx$, and $a_{n+m} = a_n + U(f, n, n+m) - \int^{n+m}_n f(x)dx$.

Furthermore, note that $f$ is always nonnegative, since it is decreasing and has limit zero.

Since $f(n) \to 0$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ such that for any $m > 0$, $f(n+m) < \epsilon$, so $0 \leq L(f, n, n+m) \leq \int_n^{n+m}f(x) \leq U(f, n, n+m) < m\epsilon$.  Therefore, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ such that for any $m >0$, $|a_{n+m} - a_n| < \epsilon$, and $a_n$ is Cauchy and converges to a limit.  QED.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user458276 Can you verify the proof? Is my solution correct? Improvements to writing?

Comment: Can someone help with this? If the question is not clear, please explain how it should be improved.

Comment: While I believe your proof is complete and sound, it can be simplified by noting that $0 \le f(m-1) - \int_{m-1}^m f(x)\,dx \le f(m-1) - f(m)$ implies a very simple upper bound for $a_n$ (telescoping series); then $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence that is bounded above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your proof is correct. In particular at the very end, where you have a bound on $U(f,n,n+m)$ of $m\epsilon$ and somehow that is enough to obtain the condition $|a_{n+m}-a_n|<\epsilon$. However I think the writing is mostly clear.

In any way, your approach introducing Riemann sums feels convoluted. Here is how I would argue:

We have
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n = f(n) - \int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx\geq 0$$
using that $f$ is decreasing. So $(a_n)$ is monotone increasing.

But also
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n = f(n)-\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx \leq f(n) - f(n+1).$$
Hence
$$ a_n \leq \sum_{i=1}^n (f(i-1)-f(i)) = f(0)-f(n)\leq f(0),$$
using that $f$ is non-negative.

So $(a_n) $ is increasing, bounded above and we are done.

I think it helps to draw a graph of $f$ out for yourself, and to see how the bound $a_n\leq f(0)$ is quite intuitive.